# Using Scipy dendrogram, set y-axis labels

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I need to plot several dendograms using Scipy. Some have their y axis values going from 0 to 1, others from 0 to 0.5 etc.

I would like to normalise the y axis so for each plot it displays values from 0 to 1 with a step of 0.2.

I think the ax argument might be what I need to set, but I do not know how to use it.